# AutoLayout breaking when displaying a view controller again

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying autolayout with textview and it works perfectly fine when the view is loaded but when I go to another viewcontroller and come back to this viewcontroller what I see is all the autolayout is lost, here are the screenshots.

This is what it looks like when the application is loaded:

[image: normal layout]

and when I go to other viewcontrollers (say 36 Blogs or Settings) and come back to Blog Posts I see that all the autolayouts are lost. Here's the screenshot of lost autolayouts:

[image: broken layout]

And this is console output when coming back to this view controller:

[image: warnings]

I'm using storyboard.

Comment: I wouldn't say AutoLayout has been completely disabled. But yes, the descriptions of the blog post are no more there and the thumbnails are slightly misplaced.

Comment: yea its happening in all tableViews , in one tableview i had 320x100 blog post thumbnail image under TextView , that image disappears as well. Trying to figure out this from 2 days.

Comment: Are you adding this constraints programmatically?

Comment: nope using storyboard

Comment: Are there any logs in the console when you leave or comeback?

Comment: yes **unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints** http://i.imgur.com/I33Za56.png same error for all views and each and every cell

Comment: Try to set an estimatedRowHeight for your tableview in viewWillDisappear, the rowHeight should be your average cell height.

Comment: @gabbler that worked, although i used some random number instead of average height :) and it works even in viewWillAppear

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have to be accurate, the 43.5 in your picture is an indication that the cell has collapsed to its default height.

Comment: i actually tried estimatedRowHeight before but in viewDidLoad, well anyways finally it worked

Comment: @gabbler I just noticed, it doesn't work in ios7, any solution for that?

Comment: That's because self sizing cells is firstly introduced in iOS 8. For iOS7, implement heightforrow method.

Comment: yes but How do i calculate heightforrow? and How do i make it this way, that heightforrowAtIndexPath function runs only in iOS 7xx, I can find the version of the phone and run this code " if version >= 8.0 { estimatedRowHeight } else run heightforrowAtIndexPath function. But I cannot call that function because its delegate, so this is where I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

I have tried creating issue you are facing. Here's what i did and try doing so what i did just set height of custom cell as I've done in the images below.

Here i've not set "heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" programmatically.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Layout Constraints
[image]

Result : 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope this solves your problem. If this still not solve your problem then pl. add screenshot of how you have set constraints to custom cell.

Comment: problem was solved using estimatedRowHeight  in viewWillDisappear. and in your cell it looks like you have set the height of textView to 42 may be thats why you got no issue, mine has top, left, right and bottom constrains because i wanted textView height to be dependent on text's length

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. It's good know that your issue is solved.

Comment: I'also checked in my demo by removing textView height well it is working fine without breaking constraints as i've set row height to 100. But you can set - self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; You can check it out it might get helpful to you in ur current issue or for setting dynamic tableView.rowHeight. Happy Coding.

Comment: yes i tried that yesterday, didn't work and then i asked here